# Problem in loging into the sandbox

Tags: email, sandbox

I am trying to login into the sandbox org,it asks for the verification code which is being sent to a mail id called ourusername.example.com. How can we get the verification code?How to check for the "example.com"?Where does it come from? Need Help 
[image]

Comment: Sandbox has been refreshed recently by someone. Everyone else's emails has been updated to invalid. Ask someone to update your email into proper one. You can find someone as guy, who refreshed sandbox in production environment

Answer (score 0):

You can't. So, fix your email in your user record in the Production instance from which you are building your sandbox. Then verify by clicking the button in the change of email address confirmation email you will receive within a few minutes. Then, and only then, create a new sandbox.